# Reverse relation (ForeignKey) in Django ORM with unique combination

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

Hi I was just wondering if this is feasible through Django ORM:

Please ignore model names etc, they are not real

```
class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    item = models.ForeignKey(Bag, related_name="images")
    flag_frontpage_image = models.BooleanField()
    imagefile = models.ImageField(upload_to="items/%m/%Y")
    ...


class Item(models.Model):
    ...
```

In views.py:

```
class LandingPageView(SomeMixin,SomeOtherMixin,ListView):
                ....
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LandingPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items'] = Item.objects.prefetch_related('images').order_by('?').all()[:10]
        return context
```

This is ok and working ok, what I want to achieve is that I want in the view to fetch in 1 query applying a join the image a well.
LandingPageView displays a list of items with the image that is flagged as frontpage image, as Django states (and SQL wise correctly) a reverse select_related is not possible, since Item can have many images, but...a Item can have only one frontpage image.
I know there are other ways of achieving this in terms of refactoring, currently since I prefer to avoid partitioning models, I follow a mixin way:

```
class GetFeaturedMixin(object):
    @property
    def featured_image(self):
        if self.images.count > 0:
            for image in self.images.all():
                if image.flag_frontpage_image == 1:
                    return image.imagefile


class Item(models.Model, GetFeaturedMixin):
    ...
```

And then in the view:

```
<img src="{{ item.featured_image }}">
```

This works fine, but I would like to know if there is a way through Django relational querysets to achieve fetching the whole set in single queryset.
Please don't answer or ask about raw queries, I know they do exist and have used them even on this type, I was just wondering if the above can be achieved with the ORM layer.

Comment: `self.images.filter(flag_frontpage_image=True)` is obviously better than pythonically iterating over all of them.

Comment: But that creates additional queries, since this is a reverse lookup, that's why I iterate through them with the above method, since the initial prefetch_related fetches all images for the items.
I am gonna check again to make sure though

Comment: Checked, I get 1 additional query for every call for featured_image so not preferred compared to the iteration.

Comment: I forgot about the prefetched alright. As for the question - I can't think of a design where the query you're doing will be available through the ORM since it's a conditioned OR calculation